# How to DeserializeObject with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json

I am deserializing an Json string to Object.This is my Json string need to Deserialized.

```
{
    "response": {
        "total_results": 33,
        "trades": [
            {
                "tid": "E231958349",
                "num": 1,
                "num_iid": 3424234,
                "price": 200.07
            }]
                }
}
```

I have defined a response model.This is my code:

```
    public class ResponseModel
    {
        public int total_results { set; get; }
        public List<TradeModel> trades{ set; get;}        
    }
```

And I also have defined trades model:

```
    public class TradeModel
    {
        #region Attribute

        #region oid
        private int tid;

        public int Oid
        {
            get { return tid; }
            set { tid = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
```

And this is my deserialize code:

```
        public static ResponseModel MapResonseJsonToModel(string json)
        {
            ResponseModel orderModel = new ResponseModel();                   
            orderModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(json);                   
            return orderModel;
        }
```

My question is:Why everytime the **total_results** return 0,and the **trades** return null?The correct is 33,and not null trade object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonConvert will be looking for a property named `response` in `ResponseModel` due to the format of your JSON. Try changing your JSON to only be the value of response, or create another class like this:

```
public class ResponseContainer
{
   public ResponseModel response {get;set;} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is probably with your JSON format. Your JSON has `response` as the outermost item and inside of that, it has two sub items namely `total_results` and `trades`. For the above code to work, your JSON should be like this :

```
{
        "total_results": 33,
        "trades": [
            {
                "tid": "E231958349",
                "num": 1,
                "num_iid": 3424234,
                "price": 200.07
            }]       
}
```

If you intend to keep as it is then change your model to something like Mike said in his answer. You can opt for either of the two ways here.

Hope this clears.